# Calculating execution time using boost::chrono

Tags: c++, boost, type-conversion, global-variables

I tried to calculate the sum of a function execution time in a loop but something goes wrong :

```
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>

boost::chrono::milliseconds sumGlobal;

int main() {
    boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 ;
    boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 ;

    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    { 
        t1 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        f(); //to waste time   
        t2 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        sumGlobal += (boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(t2-t1)).sumGlobal; 
    }          

    std::cout << sumGlobal << "\n";        
}
```

The error is:

```
error: 'struct boost::chrono::duration<long int, boost::ratio<1l, 1000l> >' has no member named 'sumGlobal'
```

Any solution ? I think that the type assigned to `sumGlobal` which should be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boost::chrono::milliseconds` doesn't return you something with a `sumGlobal` data member. Just get rid of it.

```
sumGlobal += (boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(t2-t1));
```